# Asp.net Identity logout other user

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

I'm usigin Asp.net Identity to authenticate user and I'm trying to lockout any user from admin side. But when I lockout any user who is online, It didn't logout. I have read many comments about my problem but all of them didn't work. I tried UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp to logout user but it didn't work as well.
How can I logout the user instantly when I lockout it ?

```
public ActionResult LockUser(string userId)
        {
            _userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(userId, true);
            _userManager.SetLockoutEndDate(userId,DateTime.Today.AddYears(999));

            var user = _userManager.FindById(userId);
            _userManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(userId);

            return RedirectToAction("UserDetail",new { userId });
        }


app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/UnAuthorize/Index"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {

                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<AppUserManager, User>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

Comment: That should actually do it. But this gives a minute window for the user to still use the system after you called the update security stamp. Try changing `validateInterval` to 0 in `SecurityStampValidator` and see what happens

Comment: I tried validateInterval = 0 but It didn't work again. I'm using autofac and I wonder whether this issue happens because of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are missing registration of `ApplicationUserManager` with OWIN. You still need to let OWIN know how to get user manager because it uses it to get a new security stamp for a user.

In you `Startup.Auth.cs` make sure you have this registration:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
```